# Check if a folder exist on client system in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, directory

So, I have a project in Reactjs where in I am getting some String data from JSON . and I am writing it to a file. Now I want to save this file in a folder on client side.

So is there a way to create a folder (for the first time execution) and check if a folder already exist on system. and save file on that folder?

I tried and searched a lot but couldn't find anything useful. I can save the file in downloads folder but I don't want that, I want my custom folder.

Thankyou.

Comment: Where is your application running? In the browser? In a wrapper like electron?

Comment: @Rallen on browser